# Can a UK Visitor visa be renewed after expiry or is re-application required?

Tags: visas, uk

I did have a TYPE-C multiple entry UK visa and it expired on 18/05/2016. I might potentially have to travel again this year. What is the procedure do I have to follow in order to renew my visa.

Is there any means renewal is possible? (or) Should I go through the process of re-application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'renewals' procedure (that I am aware of!) so a fresh application is your only 'choice'.

It *is* possible (in exceptional circumstances) to apply to extend the duration of stay (see [FLR(HRO)](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/application-to-extend-stay-in-the-uk-flrhro) and [FLR(IR)](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/application-to-extend-stay-in-the-uk-flrir)) but that is not the same as extending a visa.

Given that GOV.UK covers such exceptional circumstances I would expect them to cover the less exceptional "visa extension" were that possible, hence deduce that it is not.

Comment: No. Both of the forms you list are for FLR, Further Leave to Remain, and the must be completed from inside the UK. The OP is outside the UK with an expired entry clearance making this answer irrelevant to his circumstances. Please indicate the correct procedure if any, thanks.